# How to default nullable ints to 0

Tags: flutter, dart

I got a List of objects that came from a rest api, I deserialized it and got a list of MyClass, which has a property that may be null:

```
abstract class MyClass implements Built<MyClass, MyClassBuilder> {
  MyClass._();

  factory MyClass([updates(MyClassBuilder b)]) = _$MyClass;

  int get id;
  String get name;
  int get aCount;
  @nullable
  int get anotherCount;

  static Serializer<MyClass> get serializer => _$MyClassSerializer;
}
```

I have a ListTiles that has a list of MyClass which creates a text, the placeholder for `anotherCount` displays null if the value is null.

```
List<Widget> buildListTiles() {
    return _MyClassList
        .map((myClass) =>
        ListTile(
          title: Text('id: ${myClass.id}-${myClass.name}'),
          subtitle: Text(
            'aCount: ${myClass.aCount} anotherCount: ${myClass.anotherCount}',
          ),
        ))
        .toList();
  }
```

Displays:

`aCount: 5 anotherCount: null`

I want:

`aCount: 5 anotherCount: 0`

Is there a way that it can default to 0 since it's an int?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always use the `??` operator to return a default value in the case of null. For example, you could use the following to display `0` instead of `null`:

```dart
Text('aCount: ${myClass.aCount} anotherCount: ${myClass.anotherCount ?? 0}')
```

This is the equivalent of `(myClass.anotherCount != null) ? myClass.anotherCount : 0;` but much less verbose.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your

```
int get anotherCount;
```

to

```
int get anotherCount => (anotherCount != null) ? anotherCount : 0;
```

This way, if the value is null, it would return 0 instead.

Didn't know int can be null tho. I've always thought it would be 0 if unassigned/not used.

Comment: Yea it was something i found out when i was deserializing a json that had fields missing (purposely)